# Is there a better reward to be gained by completing the new Imperial Assignments?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

The "handsome rewards" aren't.

None of my Assignments give rewards that are higher than the cost of the items to build.  For example, one of them wants 16 Internal Forcefields (1875 each) AND 14 Improved Alloy (1000 each).  That means that it'd cost me 44,000 to build all of them.  Unfortunately, the reward is only 29,316.  This means it'd cost me about 14K to do the Assignment.

I don't see the point.

Is there some reason to spend more credits than the reward?  Is there some way to reduce the upfront cost, or do these assignments stack up to something more significant making it worth the expenditure?

Comment: Are you asking a question, or are you griping??

Comment: Asking.  If I'm missing something, I'd like to know.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify your question a bit.  For instance:  "Is there a later pay-off to offset the initial payment?" etc.  Am I missing something is just too broad to get a real answer.

Comment: I was trying to be broad because I wasn't sure if there was some factor I wasn't thinking about.  For example, there could be ways of reducing the cost of the item builds or ways to start building an item without paying (the original method was sending a supply officer)... or, as you stated, there could be extra rewards at the end that are in addition to the coin reward.

Comment: Allow me to help you a bit with our site.  Questions that have a narrow focus tend to get a better answer, quicker.  Broad questions frequently go unanswered, or even get closed as being "Too broad."  I would reword this question to ask a more specific question - In fact, I will edit it for you and you can always choose to roll it back if you don't like my edit.  (I'm trying to help you get an answer, not just busting your chops!)

Comment: No problem.  BTW - Please take the time to read the tour located under the help tab above.  It explains how our site works, and is also fairly entertaining.

Comment: It looks like they may have updated the costs. The same jobs, Internal Forcefield and Improved Alloy, now cost 1120 and 465 respectively, which lowers the job outlay to 24,430 and the reward is the same at 29,316 making the reward better than the cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every new Imperial item you finish building earns you some medals, and when accumulated to a certain number will net you some limited edition rewards.

The aim of getting these limited edition rewards is what keeps me churning out those new Imperial items, even if the direct benefits does not cover the costs.

There are also non-monetary rewards such as VIPs or Imperial Bucks.

[image]

[image]

[image: Imperial Bucks reward]

Comment: Additionally, some missions have non-monetary rewards.  For example, when I completed the second Sith Demands mission, I received VIP cargo.  When I unpacked the cargo, it filled my lobby with 4 VIP Level Movers (I already had one in my lobby), for a total of 5 VIPs in my lobby after completing that mission.

Comment: @rbf2000 You really should have posted that as a separate answer.  It's a pretty big edit for one.  And, two, you deserve rep for it.

Comment: I appreciate the response!  When I first started playing this update, the 10 day event had not yet started, so it was not apparent.  Now that it has, I'm dutifully working on filling up the progress bar.  I will be interested to see what happens to continue the value after the event ends in ten days.